# gitlab CI/CD: caching docker image build

Tags: docker, gitlab

I was trying to understand how to cache the docker image build layers while building images using docker CI/CD

[image]

But in this process we have to first pull the image. Sometimes even that can be overhead.

Comment: Each new pipeline job means new environment. If you are running on shared runners on gitlab.com you have to pull that image first.

Comment: If i am not using shared runners then how can this be done. I have created my own runner

Comment: Ok so it completely depends on how you have your runner configured. Please provide your `config.toml` file.

Comment: I can't figure out why they use the current project's commit hash as a tag. It's only if the docker image changes that it's useful to rebuild it, not if this project that pulls it and uses it does, don't you think?
It assumes that the Dockerfile is part of this projet, whereas it could just be part of another project.

Comment: Also... my live tests in GitLab CI/CD, with and without --cache-from, don't yield any substantial difference. The docker build process only takes about 27 s, and still takes 27 s if I replay the job many times that is supposed to use the cache... I can't figure out how to save a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have configured your own runner.

If you are using socket binding, by mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` you will use the Docker daemon from the host machine of the Runner and you can use the cache of layers without further ado.

If you are using Docker-in-Docker, so using the `docker:dind` service, you should enable registry mirror so you aren't downloading the images from internet each time. In any case, what you want cannot be done in Docker-in-Docker, since each job runs in a new environment, so there's no caching of layers.

From the official documentation:

> Limitations of Docker-in-Docker
> Docker-in-Docker is the recommended configuration, but is not without its own challenges:
>
> The docker-compose command: This command is not available in this configuration by default. To use docker-compose in your job scripts, follow the docker-compose installation instructions.
>
> **Cache: Each job runs in a new environment. Concurrent jobs work fine, because every build gets its own instance of Docker engine and they don’t conflict with each other. However, jobs can be slower because there’s no caching of layers.**
>
> Storage drivers: By default, earlier versions of Docker use the vfs storage driver, which copies the file system for each job. Docker 17.09 and later use --storage-driver overlay2, which is the recommended storage driver. See Using the OverlayFS driver for details.
>
> Root file system: Because the docker:19.03.12-dind container and the runner container don’t share their root file system, you can use the job’s working directory as a mount point for child containers. For example, if you have files you want to share with a child container, you might create a subdirectory under /builds/$CI_PROJECT_PATH and use it as your mount point. For a more detailed explanation, view issue #41227.

Comment: so whats the solution, using `/var/run/docker.sock` is the only solution?

Comment: If you want to have cache in the build layers, yes.

Comment: Let me mitigate this answer, about the "new environment" point, since there is now a Docker layer caching in GitLab. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/docker_layer_caching.html